# Do I need acpid daemon in virtualization guest?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, acpi

I get VPS with KVM virtualisation (server for hosting services).

I remove most of desktop services (like `dbus`, `consolekit`, `xorg`) because of security and stability concern.

Guest run on virtualised hardware and ACPI table is emulated. Guest is not supposed to be suspend or hibernated.

I wonder are there a need for `acpid`?

According to `aptitude` package manager `acpid` is not a *base* packages and removing it doesn't broke dependencies.

Comment: Only if you want to be able to suspend and shutdown the guest from the host!

Comment: `/sbin/reboot` and `/sbin/shutdown` provided by `systemd-sysv` or `sysvinit-core` or `upstart` packages. Do I still able to reboot system without *aspid* daemon?

Comment: After removing `acpid` I successfully reboot host!